# jQuery load txt file .html()

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

how can I decode the html contents of the .txt file when using the `$('myDiv').load('mytxtFile.txt')`?

I know: `$('<div/>').html(value).text();`

In other words, How do I combine these two?

important note:  the mytextFile.txt, is the container of some of codes which jenerated with ckeditor, and i want to show the content of this txt file in my html form as a html form.

the codes in my txt file is:

```
&lt;p&gt;hellohome&lt;/p&gt;
```

and I want to show it as : sss hello home sss
in my html page

tank you for your attantion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're after something like this:

```
 $('<div/>').load('mytextFile.txt', function(textStr) {
    var htmlStr = $(this).html(textStr).text(); 
    $(this).html(htmlStr);
 }).appendTo('form');
```

That'll effectively encode the html entities, return a properly formed `htmlStr`, which you can use to set the `html()` of the element.

#### [Here's a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gX8dG/2/)

Comment: thanks advance for your greate help.
 but the best solution for me is: 
}$('<div/>').load('mytextFile.txt', function(textStr) { var htmlStr = $(this).html(textStr).text(); $(this).html(htmlStr); });

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you can do this:

```
$('myDiv').load('mytxtFile.txt', function(text) {
  $(this).text(text);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but please attantion to my question again, (i have edited my question).

Comment: @user2675149 I'm still not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `load()` is designed to pull fragments of HTML directly into the document. If you want to preprocess the data, then load it using `$.ajax` instead and write your own logic for updating the element content with `success`.

```
success: function (data) {
    $('myDiv').text(data);  // Note: Your selector but not one that is valid for an HTML document
}
```

Comment: seems like `.laod()` can achieve this if the file is local.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the textfile with `$.ajax` and then add the text with "`$('#YOURDIV').text(data)`"

Example:
Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXMha/

HTML:

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        html: "<p>Text echoed back to request</p>" + "<script type='text/javascript'>$('target').highlight();<\/script>",
        delay: 0
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('#text').text(data);
    }
})
```

Output:

```
<p>Text echoed back to request</p><script type='text/javascript'>$('target').highlight();</script>
```

Note: Post is used in this example to simulate an ajax call where html is returned. See http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html for Fiddler echo HTML Options.

For your second question: you can simply post the text with .html(data) into your div.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        html: "&lt;p&gt;hellohome&lt;/p&gt;",
        delay: 0
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('#text').html(data);
    }
})
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/KWpUC/

Comment: ok, but next time make a new question if you want additional details